# MiG Layout, JScrollBar and JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, layout, jscrollpane, jtabbedpane

I have a JFrame with it's content pane. JMenuBar is docked on the north of the pane and JLabel (status bar of sorts) on the south.

In the middle is a JTabbedPane. Each tab is a "document". It contains a JScrollBar and a JPanel in it's viewport.

It goes on and on (JPanel of the viewport has more JPanels, that can have more of them, etc...), but for this example, lets just say that that JPanel (in the viewport) can, or cannot fit into the window space (so it cannot, or can force scrollBars to be represented on the screen).

When it fits the window, everyting is fine, but as soon as I set it's height to be too hight to fit inside a window, JMenuBar gets squished on the top.

I'd like to prevent that (without having to specify the absolute height for the JMenuBar, it'd probably work, but it's kind of cheap), since it shouldn't happen in the first place.

Here's SCCE (It's not really short, but you only need to look at the lines 37 to 117, and I have marked all the lines that have something to do with layout with //TODO). Also, to see when problem occurs or when it doesn't occur, change height value in the line 88 inbetween 2000 and 200. You also need a MiG Layout library, of course.

Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

class Menu extends JMenuBar
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Menu()
    {
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("file"); 
        this.add(fileMenu);
    }
}

class DisplayGUI
{
    JTabbedPane documentSelector;

    void addNewDocument(String name)
    {
        Document newDocument = new Document();
        newDocument.addChapter(new Chapter(), 1);
        documentSelector.add(newDocument, name);
    }

    public DisplayGUI()
    {   
        JFrame masterWindow = new JFrame("name");

        masterWindow.setSize(1100, 800);
        masterWindow.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        masterWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        masterWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel rootPanel = new JPanel();
        rootPanel.setLayout(new MigLayout()); //TODO Here is layout set for the content pane of the main JFrame

        Menu menuBar = new Menu();
        rootPanel.add(menuBar, "span, north"); //TODO Here is menu bar added to the JFrame, it's docked north

        JLabel statusBar = new JLabel("Welcome to PLabScript editor! Press File>New to create a new file or go to File>Open to open an existing one.");
        statusBar.setOpaque(true);
        statusBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLoweredSoftBevelBorder());
        rootPanel.add(statusBar, "span, south"); //TODO Here is status bar added to the JFrame, it's docked south

        documentSelector = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.NORTH); //TODO JTabbedPane set so the tab chooser is on the top
        rootPanel.add(documentSelector, "grow, push"); //TODO setup so it will take up all the remaining space


        addNewDocument("Brand new document");       


        masterWindow.setContentPane(rootPanel);
        masterWindow.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Document extends JScrollPane
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JPanel basePanel;

    //methods
    void addChapter(Chapter chapter, int index)
    {
        basePanel.add(chapter, "grow, push, h 2000", index-1); //TODO this here adds a chapter to the basePanel of the JScrollPane which is the a representative of a single document
        //TODO it height is set to 2000 (and the problem occurs), but if you reduce it enough so it fits the window, problem will dissaper 
    }

    //constructors
    public Document()
    {
        super(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(20);

        basePanel = new JPanel();
        basePanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        basePanel.setLayout(new MigLayout("insets 0")); //TODO "insets 0" is so there is no border thingy around all of the child components

        setViewportView(basePanel);
    }

}

class Chapter extends JPanel
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //constructors
    Chapter()
    {
        setLayout(new MigLayout("insets 0")); //TODO "insets 0" is so there is no border thingy around all of the child components
        setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
    }
}


public class Main
{
    public static ResourceBundle language;

    static boolean setUpLAF()
    {
        for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels())
        {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName()))
            {
                try
                {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                }
                catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e)

                {
                    return false;
                }

                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {       
        //SetUpLookAndFeel
        setUpLAF(); 

        //Display actual GUI
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new DisplayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: what version of miglayout?

Comment: 4.0, I just got it the other day.

Comment: Could it be a bug? Should I submit it to the developers?

Comment: Is there a way around it? Except setting the height manually, that is...

Comment: I think better to ask in Miglayout mailing list. And submit them your code, probably they will suggest something. I doubt you will get quick response on SO.

Comment: I don't now. I tried setting it's height manually, but it's not working...

Comment: my suggestion below should work. at least does not squish menubar

Answer (score 1):

Line 88 should read:

```
    basePanel.add(chapter, "grow, push", index-1); //TODO this here adds a chapter to the basePanel of the JScrollPane which is the a representative of a single document
```

Line 100 should read:

```
    basePanel.setLayout(new MigLayout("fill,insets 0")); //TODO "insets 0" is so there is no border thingy around all of the child components
```

Try this.

Comment: I tried, but I can't avoid setting an absolute height of the component. I don't have to set the height of this particular one, but it contains a "page" which has a predefined height, along with it's header and footer.

So I couldn't really change the line 88 (it already is that in my program, but it's children all have defined heights), and changing no. 100 did nothing then.